# Rank quantifiers based on intensity

Tags: quantifiers, intensifiers

Is there any ranking for quantifiers based on intensity (pretty, quite, very, etc..) in English?

Comment: Too many questions and no research.

Comment: While Lambie's comment is blunt, it is site policy that questions be reasonably scoped and also [show "research"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/41273). The linked question explains this better, but your thoughts on the matter and the "research" you've done (e.g., in dictionaries) should be in the question itself. You're not helping anyone help you if you're keeping this information to yourself. Hope that explains things

Answer (score 5):

You are acting like a lawyer or mathematician, but natural languages aren't like mathematical expressions or legal terms.

"very" is a general intensifier.  "fairly" would tend to make it weaker, and so would "quite"

But it's pointless to try to rank "rather" compared to "pretty" or "fairly" with "quite".

Moreover, in the right context "quite" can be an intensifier (meaning "completely"). Or "rather" can overlap with "very", or "pretty" can mean "fairly" etc.

So a very rough ranking might be

- very (strongest)
- rather pretty
- quite fairly

But there is a lot of overlap between the levels.

Comment: _Pretty much similar_ means _almost exactly the same_.

Comment: "pretty much the same" means "almost exactly the same".  "Pretty much similar" would mean "Almost exactly similar". But that is not a sensible thing to say. So I've not included it in my list.

Comment: +1 And to add that "quite" has quite a different meaning in North American English. It's stronger than "rather" over here, closer to "very". This leads to misunderstandings, especially as most AmE/BrE speakers aren't aware that it's different on the other side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @gotube - In the UK, saying someone is 'quite beautiful' can mean that the speaker thinks they are very beautiful indeed, but 'quite pretty' just means 'so-so'.

Answer (score 2):

These terms do have different implications. They can't be ranked against each other, but most of the ones you listed fall into two categories:

- Terms that are vague and general, like "somewhat," and don't make a strong implication of either "a little" or "a lot":

  - rather similar
  - fairly similar
- Terms that imply "a lot":

  - quite similar (but see comments on James K's answer)
  - pretty similar
  - pretty much similar (this is the strongest of all these)
  - very similar